# How to delete entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a Many-to-Many relationship (driver is the main thing), using Jpa Repository I try to delete an entity, but I get this exception:

```
2022-01-10 23:36:10.664  INFO 24152 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.b.internal.AbstractBatchImpl     : HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
2022-01-10 23:36:10.665 ERROR 24152 --- [           main] o.h.e.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchingBatch  : HHH000315: Exception executing batch [java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`taxi_bd_test`.`driver_car`, CONSTRAINT `FK30pax2ryivkt4kcm8ul9w3uok` FOREIGN KEY (`car_id`) REFERENCES `car` (`id`))], SQL: delete from Car where id=?
2022-01-10 23:36:10.665  WARN 24152 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1451, SQLState: 23000
2022-01-10 23:36:10.665 ERROR 24152 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`taxi_bd_test`.`driver_car`, CONSTRAINT `FK30pax2ryivkt4kcm8ul9w3uok` FOREIGN KEY (`car_id`) REFERENCES `car` (`id`))

org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute batch; SQL [delete from Car where id=?]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute batch

    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:210)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateTransactionManager.java:785)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:655)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:743)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:711)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:654)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:407)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:753)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:698)
    at ua.com.alevel.persistence.crud.impl.CrudRepositoryHelperImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$39a61dd0.delete(<generated>)
    at ua.com.alevel.service.impl.DriverServiceImpl.delete(DriverServiceImpl.java:51)
    at ua.com.alevel.service.impl.DriverServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$c63a6014.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689)
    at ua.com.alevel.service.impl.DriverServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$55260f0f.delete(<generated>)
    at ua.com.alevel.RepositoryApplicationTests.hDeleteDriver(RepositoryApplicationTests.java:153)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:84)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute batch
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:37)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchingBatch.performExecution(BatchingBatch.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchingBatch.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatch.java:106)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl.execute(AbstractBatchImpl.java:148)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.executeBatch(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:198)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:633)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.lambda$executeActions$1(ActionQueue.java:478)
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:721)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:475)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:344)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1402)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:493)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3285)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2420)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:449)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:183)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$300(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:281)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:101)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:643)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`taxi_bd_test`.`driver_car`, CONSTRAINT `FK30pax2ryivkt4kcm8ul9w3uok` FOREIGN KEY (`car_id`) REFERENCES `car` (`id`))
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at com.mysql.cj.util.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:192)
    at com.mysql.cj.util.Util.getInstance(Util.java:167)
    at com.mysql.cj.util.Util.getInstance(Util.java:174)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createBatchUpdateException(SQLError.java:224)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeBatchSerially(ClientPreparedStatement.java:853)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeBatchInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:435)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeBatch(StatementImpl.java:800)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchingBatch.performExecution(BatchingBatch.java:121)
    ... 66 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`taxi_bd_test`.`driver_car`, CONSTRAINT `FK30pax2ryivkt4kcm8ul9w3uok` FOREIGN KEY (`car_id`) REFERENCES `car` (`id`))
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:117)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:953)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1098)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeBatchSerially(ClientPreparedStatement.java:832)
    ... 69 more
```

I understand that I have an error when binding entities to each other using hibernate, but I do not know how to fix it:(

How I create a relationship:
Car:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "cars")
private Set<Driver> drivers;
```

Driver:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = {
        CascadeType.PERSIST,
        CascadeType.MERGE
})
@JoinTable(name = "driver_car",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "driver_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "car_id")
)
private Set<Car> cars;
```

I have a CrudRepositoryHelper where I have described for these entities CRUD, findBy and findAll, give you the delete code:

```
@Override
@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.REPEATABLE_READ)
public void delete(R repository, Long id) {
    checkById(repository, id);
    repository.deleteById(id);
}
```

How do I try to remove Car:

```
@Override
public void delete(Long id) {
    crudRepositoryHelper.delete(carRepository, id);
}
```

How do I try to remove Driver:

```
@Override
public void delete(Long id) {
    Set<Car> cars = findById(id).get().getCars();
    for(Car car: cars){
        if(car.getDrivers().size() <= 1){
            crudRepositoryHelperCar.delete(carRepository, car.getId());
        }
    }
    crudRepositoryHelper.delete(driverRepository, id);
}
```

Although, when I worked with Jpa, and not JpaRepository (with the same connections and delete) everything worked fine, but now for some reason it does not work

Delete Car in Jpa:

```
 @Override
    public void delete(Long id) {
        entityManager.createQuery("delete from Car s where s.id = :id")
                .setParameter("id", id)
                .executeUpdate();
    }
```

Delete Driver in Jpa:

```
@Override
public void delete(Long id) {
    entityManager.createQuery("delete from Driver d where d.id = :id")
            .setParameter("id", id)
            .executeUpdate();
}
```

Comment: You have a driver that has a car that you are deleting -what do you want to happen with that driver? Personally, I'd like a notification if the repo man or some other entity is deleting my car - and at very least the opportunity to fix my list of cars and remove the entry. Your code should do that as well (JPA requires it), or use the cascade delete option if your car is being deleted and the driver should be deleted too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cascade for Delete is not there it will not delete the relation when you are deleting the Car entity.

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = {
        CascadeType.ALL
}, orphanremoval = true)
@JoinTable(name = "driver_car",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "driver_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "car_id")
)
private Set<Car> cars;
```

Comment: If I am not mistaken, then CascadeType.All and Remove are not recommended for many-to-Many relationship.

Comment: This isn't true - it just isn't likely to be what you really want. Deleting a car (or driver in this case) shouldn't automatically delete the driver (or car), which is what cascade remove and orphan removal do. Many confuse how to handle entries in the relation table and assume cascade operations tell JPA to remove those when they really apply to the referenced entity. JPA will automatically delete the reference table rows for you, but only if you dereference the entity. No need for cascade or ophan removal unless you want everything cleared out when removing one object from the graph.